# Better way to deal with optional variable and array operation in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

I have a following code, which copies an array of Rider objects, and appends a new Rider object if it exists.

```
let riders:[Rider] = getRiders()
let newRider:Rider? = mayGetNewRider()
var ridersPlus = riders
if let rider = newRider {
   ridersPlus.append(rider)
}
```

I am looking for a better (simpler and easier to read) way to write this logic, which also allows me to define ridersPlus as "let" variable.

I am looking for something like below (which is invalid, because I made up the ??? syntax, which produces an empty array of newRider is nil).

```
let riders:[Rider] = getRiders()
let newRider:Rider? = mayGetNewRider()
let ridersPlus = riders + [newRider???]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
let ridersPlus = riders + [newRider].compactMap {$0}
```

(Note that before Swift 4, `compactMap` would be called `flatMap`. You didn't say what Swift version you are using.)

Answer (score 1):

You do it with `map` and the *nil coalescing operator* `??`:

```
let ridersPlus = riders + (newRider.map {[$0]} ?? [])
```

`map` when called on an *Optional* value evaluates the given closure when the *Optional* instance is not `nil`, passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.  If the *Optional* is `nil`, the result of the `map` is `nil`.  Combining that with the *nil coalescing operator*, the resulting *Optional* array can be unwrapped or replaced with `[]` and then added to the `riders` array.